# Как закрепить элемент внизу экрана

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ui, nested-scrollview

Пишу приложение придерживаясь Single-Activity Architecture, управление фрагментами осуществляю с помощью навигационного графика. На данный момент столкнулась с проблемой фиксации view в нижней части экрана, так как фрагменты вставляются в NestedScrollView.

Что я имею:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне нужно: всё тоже самое, но EditText ("Добавить комментарий") с кнопкой должны быть фиксированы и всегда видны.

XML для вставки фрагментов выглядит следующим образом:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:id="@+id/scroll_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <fragment
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:id="@+id/navHost"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        /> </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Разметка для содержимого:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layoutViewComment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Layout для Изображения  -->
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Views для описания изображения -->
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<!--Часть с RecyclerView и EditText-->
<include layout="@layout/comments_view"
    android:id="@+id/comment_include"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

XML для списка комментариев и ввода своего комментария:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Заголовок Title -->
<TextView
    style="@style/title"
    android:id="@+id/title_comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/comment"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
<!--Layout for comments-->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_comment"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/line_comment"
   />

<!-- view line-->
<View
    android:id="@+id/line_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    style="@style/line_blue"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_toleave_comment"/>
<!-- leave a comment-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_toleave_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/add_comment"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        style="@style/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"/>

</LinearLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Что я пыталась сделать:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Но в таком случае комментарии "запираются" между картинкой и EditText:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было много и других попыток, но ничего существенного не получалось, понимаю, что основная проблема именно в том, что фрагмент находится внутри прокрутки. Буду рада любой помощи.

Comment: Можно попробовать просто корнем поставить вертикальный LinearLayout, дальше ваш NestedSV (heght=0dp layout_weight=1) и внизу EditText (height=wrap_content)

Comment: Этот вариант у меня на самый крайний случай, так как не хотелось бы "засорять" разметку активити, а за пределами NestedSV именно она и есть.(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым.

Так как в фиксации нуждалась только нижняя часть фрагмента, а изображение нуждалось в прокрутке как и RecylerView, было решено добавить верхнюю часть в качестве Header к RecyclerView.
Для реализации понадобилось воспользоваться getItemViewType и немного подправить адаптер:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Model> mModels;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models) {
    mContext = context;
    mModels = models;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
        if(viewType ==TYPE_ITEM)
    {
    // Here Inflating your recyclerview item layout
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View post = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, parent, false);
    Adapter.CViewHolder cViewHolder = new Adapter.CViewHolder(post);
    return cViewHolder;
    } else if(viewType ==TYPE_HEADER)
            {
                // Here Inflating your header view
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false);
                return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
            }
   else return null;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder){
        HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        // You have to set your header items 
       
    }
    else if (holder instanceof CViewHolder){
        final CViewHolder itemHolder = (CViewHolder) holder;
        // Following code give a row of header and decrease the one position from listview items
        Model model = mModels.get(position-1);
        // You have to set your listview items
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModels.size()+1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

public class CViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView one, two, three;

    public CViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        one = itemView.findViewById(R.id.one);
        two = itemView.findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = itemView.findViewById(R.id.three);
    }
}

public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView photo;

    public HeaderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content_photo);
    }
}
```

В разметке самого RecyclerView не забыть установить android:layout_height="0dp"

Надеюсь это сможет помочь кому-нибудь.)

[image: Вот что из этого вышло]